# Online Polynomial Calculators for Large Polynomials

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials

Looking for an online polynomial calculator that can fully expand (with grouping like terms) $(c_1x_1 + c_2x_2 + c_3x_3 + c_4x_4 + c_5x_5)^9$

Comment: Wolfram Alpha can do this stuff, but if you're gonna do stuff like that (you have 10 variables), it's not gonna be pretty. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(c_1x_1+%2B+c_2x_2+%2B+c_3x_3+%2B+c_4x_4+%2B+c_5x_5)%5E9

Answer (score 0):

It's $$\sum_{\sum\limits_{i=1}^5k_i=9,k_i\geq0,k_i\in\mathbb Z}\binom{9}{k_1,k_2,k_3,k_4,k_5}c_1^{k_1}c_2^{k_2}c_3^{k_3}c_4^{k_4}c_5^{k_5}x_1^{k_1}x_2^{k_2}x_3^{k_3}x_4^{k_4}x_5^{k_5}$$